# Elastic Search - give preference to perfect match

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I'm new to elastic.

I'm using elastic search to search on the title field of documents stored in my database. More info: `"title" field - type "String"/indexed and "title.unanalyzed" field - type "String"/unindexed`.

I want the document whose title has a perfect match with the query to occur at the top of the search results while for all others, I want the them to be sorted in decending order of score. I guess giving a score of 1.1 to documents with exactly matched title will help as elastic scores between 0 and 1 for analyzed fields. My current query:

```
query: {
                    term: {
                            "title.unanalyzed": "some_title"
                    },

                    multi_match: {
                            query: "some_title",
                            type: "most_fields",
                            fields: ["title", "other"]
                    }
        }
```

gives an error: `failed to parse search source. expected field name but got [START_OBJECT]`. Need help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "title.unanalyzed": "some_title"
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "some_title",
            "type": "most_fields",
            "fields": [
              "title",
              "other"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```